# How to use variable value as file name in curl

Tags: bash, macos, shell

I am looping through urls in a file to download their data and each url represents data for each hour of the day. I want to name the file the date and hour that it comes from. The following doesn't work, but I'm not quite sure why

```
myDate=$(date -v -1d '+%Y/%m/%d')
for hour in {0..23}
do
   ...
   ...
   #set file name
   name=$myDate.$hour.txt
   curl -L -o $name "https://..."
done
```

I think it's just a problem with the syntax for $name in the curl statement, but I don't know how to correct it.

I get the following error

```
Warning: Failed to create the file 2019/09/18-0: No such file or directory
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 16360)
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`date -v -1d '+%Y/%m/%d'` returns a string containing slashes, which are used as path separators, so, for example, in:

```
iMac-ForceBru:~ forcebru$ date -v -1d '+%Y/%m/%d'
2019/09/18
```

The `2019/09/18` would be treated as a file called `18` in directory `09`, which is in turn inside directory `2019`. It looks like the path `2019/09` doesn't exist on your system, so the file `2019/09/something.txt` can't be created.